# Magento Third API integration

Tags: php, rest, api, soap, magento-1.9

What is the right way to integrate third party api in magento . Logistic API integration is provided , but need help with the right process to make it work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: first define whether you want to consume or provide an api from magento.

Comment: I want to send order details to logistic in request And ill get some response data .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to consume an external API from Magento this would be the correct structure:

1. For Application related logic create a Module in local namespace
   (/app/code/local/(vendor-name)/(module-name))
2. Enable your Module with an xml in /app/etc/modules/
3. Put your Api related libraries or logic under /lib/
4. Make use of Api libraries in Models under
   /app/code/local/(vendor-name)/(module-name)/Model

**UPDATE:**

I found a sample Magento 1 Module on github, that simply consumes google weather api.

https://github.com/careys7/Magento-Weather-Sales

Comment: is there any sample working example where i can get more details about it. thank you for the effort and explanation..ill try to use it.

Comment: see my updated answer. you are welcome. don't forget to upvote and accept if it helped :)

Comment: Is there an example of the opposite direction request? A custom (not existing yet) API endpoint in Magento to be publicly accessible. Magento 1.9.

Comment: @VladimirVukanac I won't come up with an example but it is for sure possible. I however can't think of a reason why not to extend existing magento api and reuse all the authentication funcionality.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution could be, especially when trying to integrate an API that's not directly supported by Magento, to use [flowground](https://flowground.net/en). It offers flexible API integration for thousands of APIs with dedicated connectors, e.g. Magento 1 and Magento 2.

Check the [list of integrated connectors](https://flowground.net/en/platform/connector-catalog) and [GitHub](https://github.com/flowground) for the list of available Open-Source connectors.